# How to select only records that contain a unique value in a certain column

Tags: sql, select

I have a table (tbl_payments) with 4 columns like this:

```
+------------+------------+-------+------------+  
| User_id    | Name       | Status|  Payment No|
+------------+------------+-------+------------+
```

Now imagine records like this.

```
1| Luigi | Active | 1
1| Luigi | Active | 2
1| Luigi | Active | 3
2| Peach | Active | 1
2| Peach | Active | 2
2| Peach | Paid   | 3
3| Bowser| Active | 1
3| Bowser| Active | 2
3| Bowser| OFF    | 3
```

I need a query that returns only users that have one unique status, for example, our query would return:

```
1| Luigi | Active
```

I have tried a subquery without success, any clue would be amazing, thank you guys in advance.

Comment: "our query would return" what?

Comment: Fixed it, thanks @Lamak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select user_id, name, max(status)
from t
group by user_id, name
having min(status) = max(status);
```

Comment: not wrong but  `having count(distinct status)=1` might be a more obvious syntax to the requirement.

Comment: @LoztInSpace . . . I tend to be wary of `count(distinct)` in this case.  Although it works fine when there are a handful of different values, it might do unnecessary work if there are lots of values.

Comment: Yes that's a good point. Depending on the data keeping tabs on min/max is likely cheaper and more consistent than tracking distinct values.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it works

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR
DECLARE @STATUS VARCHAR

SELECT *
FROM   tbl_payments
WHERE  Name = @NAME,
       Status = @STATUS
GROUP BY user_id, Name
```